# Text to speech android query

Tags: android, eclipse, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, android-alertdialog

I am trying to implement Text to speech for my app. When my app starts up an alert box is shown saying "Welcome to my App".

Is it possible to speak out the text within an alert box?

I've researched Text to speech and they are all speaking out String, which I don't want to do.

This is my alert box. The text is within another class called AppResources

```
  // Alertbox before start
    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    dlgAlert.setMessage(AppResources.ALERT_MSG);
    dlgAlert.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
    dlgAlert.create().show();
```

Thank You

Comment: it´s only possible to speak out a string...what else should TTS speak...a long?

Comment: Within App Resources the message is a string.
public static String ALERT_MSG = "Welcome To My App";

Comment: getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) you can assign it to string and then assign it to TTS to speak bc its also a string

Comment: Thanks for you help but I've managed to work it out
tts.speak(AppResources.ALERT_MSG, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
That works fine